# Upgrading my Free trial Azure Devops version to LIcensed

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server

I am trying to Upgrade my free trial Azure DevOps to a licensed version but i don't see any options to apply my licenses.
Is there a way to apply our new licenses without having to re-install?

Comment: On promise or cloud azure DevOps?

Comment: @Vinny Hi ,Vinny Is the explanation given in my answer helpful? If you have any question ,please kindly let me know.:)

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions, TFS included code which required a valid product key to be present in order for the server to start up.

Since TFS 2015.2, TFS no longer distinguish the versions in this way, so there is no product key left on the TFS Admin console Product Information Summary page to display. And the TfsConfig License command is not available since TFS 2015.2.

If your TFS is in a Trial, it will not stop work immediately. If your trial expires, you will see a banner in most pages of the TFS Web UI. You would have enough time to complete trial.After you get the trial expiration warning message, you could select the 'complete the trial of my TFS Deployment'. There does not have a field to let you input the TFS Key.

What's more, when the trial is completed, all users should be assigned an appropriate access level based on the licenses they have. An unlimited number of users who only need access to work items can be added as Stakeholders and will not require any license. Most other users who access your server will require a license.

To use later TFS version, need to buy monthly access. You could find more information in this link:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/buy-access-tfs-test-hub

You can refer to this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/team-foundation-server-update-2-trial/) and these cases([#1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be169a6c-64e5-47c5-8cff-80693b71bff2/how-to-update-product-key-for-tfs-20152-?forum=tfsadmin),[#2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/580144/tfs-2018-license-update.html)).